# How do I make elements align in an absolute layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I need to align a set of text fields in an absolute layout. Here I'm posting an image. I want to make these text fields vertically and horizontally align. I showed only three sets but in my real app want to add up to 10 sets. To me it is very difficult to align them.

[image]

I'm a beginner Android developer so I don't have proper idea how to do this. Please explain me what is the best way to do this.

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="81dp"
    android:layout_y="56dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="202dp"
    android:layout_y="58dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="82dp"
    android:layout_y="130dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="205dp"
    android:layout_y="127dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText04"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="82dp"
    android:layout_y="197dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText05"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="205dp"
    android:layout_y="196dp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look at [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). Using `AbsoluteLayout` is discouraged since Android 1.5 or so. Since it is absolute it can't adjust for different screen-sizes and aspects and the layout will look broken on every device except for the one you used to design the layout.

Comment: How can I add text fields to grid view ? please help..

Comment: @Grant : Don't use `AbsoluteLayout`...never, ever. It's evil. Use nested `LinearLayouts` with `layout_weight` to proportionally space UI elements horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Don't use AbsoluteLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this in `Tablelayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```